# Swapping Cropped Images in Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, drawimage

I want to swap two circular cuts from an image and swap their locations and draw them to the canvas.  I am having issues, however, drawing the second circular image.  Interestingly in `second` if you uncomment the first line it draws that image, otherwise if you throw it at the end of the function, it doesn't draw (at least on top).  If I comment out the first function, I get the image to draw on the canvas.  The first function always executes before the second.

```
function first() {
      ctx.drawImage(imgBig, 0, 0);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(imgObj1.x + imgObj1.width / 2, imgObj1.y + imgObj1.width / 2, imgObj1.width / 2, 0, 6.28, false);
      ctx.clip();
      ctx.stroke(); // the outline of circle
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.drawImage(imgBig, imgObj2.x, imgObj2.y, imgObj2.width, imgObj2.height, imgObj1.x, imgObj1.y, imgObj1.width, imgObj1.height);

function second() {
      // ctx.drawImage(imgCuttingBoard, 0, 0); // this will draw over canvas
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(imgObj2.x + imgObj2.width / 2, imgObj2.y + imgObj2.width / 2, imgObj2.width / 2, 0, 6.28, false);
      ctx.clip();
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.drawImage(imgCuttingBoard, imgObj1.x, imgObj1.y, imgObj1.width, imgObj1.height, imgObj2.x, imgObj2.y,
      imgObj2.width, imgObj2.height); // this doesn't draw on top of the image (might be drawing underneath?)
      // ctx.drawImage(imgCuttingBoard, 0, 0); // this will not draw over canvas here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have given the image time to fully load before trying to `drawImage` it. You did use `image.onload` and wait for image to load?

Then your problem is likely clipping ...

`context.clip` is cumulative. If one clip (clip#1) is applied to the canvas followed by another clip (clip#2), then the resulting clipping area is the intersection of clip#1 and clip#2. The resulting clip is not clip#2.

So if you want to undo clip#1 so you can use the full clip#2, you must wrap the first clip in `context.save` and `context.restore`.

**Here's a slightly different way of doing it using a temporary canvas**

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/faces%20no%20background.png";
function start(){
    cw=canvas.width=img.width;
    ch=canvas.height=img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    // do the swap
    clipCircle(img,63.5,56,54,203,177);
    clipCircle(img,203,177,54,63.5,56);
}

function clipCircle(img,sourceCX,sourceCY,r,newCX,newCY){
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
    c.width=2*r;
    c.height=2*r;
    
    // define an clipping circle 
    cctx.beginPath();
    cctx.arc(r,r,r,0,Math.PI*2);
    // draw the source into the temp canvas
    cctx.drawImage(img,-sourceCX+r,-sourceCY+r);
    // draw the temp canvas onto the main canvas
    ctx.drawImage(c,newCX-r,newCY-r);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>Swapped clipping on canvas<br>(top-left swapped with bottom-center)</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<h4>Original Image</h4>
<img src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/faces%20no%20background.png'>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I literally just found this answer a second ago.  Problem was the lack of .save() and .restore() methods.